# app.config on other location than the location of .exe

Tags: .net, app-config

I have a WPF application which is by default installed in programs files folder.

At runtime, app.config file is modified and saved. Based on this modifications, enterprise library logs application logging.

But on windows 10 machine, modifications of app.config files are not saved due to security issues.

I tried below option but enterprise library continue to read app.config from original location.

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE",  _tempFolderPath + "\DMSShell.exe.config");

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Configuration.Save` at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134088(v=vs.110).aspx.

Take a look at the notes on that page about ACL though to ensure you have correct user permissins.